# Subscribe to an Angular Reactive Form submittal

Tags: angular, rxjs

I wanted to initialize a subscription to an Angular form's submittal instead of value changes. Basically, in my head I wanted something along the lines of this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup.submit.pipe(
    mergeMap(this.service.update(formVal)),
  ).subscribe(this.val$);
}
```

That way I can initialize a subscription to the form change from the start directly from the form, the source of the value changes. Is this possible? Why or why not?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this approach, providing the form has no realtime frontend validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> initialize a subscription to an Angular form's submittal instead of value changes

There's a way to do this. When you create a form control(`FormControl`, `FormGroup` or `FormArray`), you can also specify the `updateOn` property, which indicates when the form control should be updated. When a form control is updated, its `valueChanges` and `statusChanges` subjects will emit as well.

With that in mind, you could create your `FormGroup` instance like this:

```js
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({ /* ... controls ... */ }, { updateOn: 'submit' })

// Getting notified about changes
this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(formValue => {})
```

The possible values for `updateOn` are: `change`, `blur` and `submit`.

[Here](https://indepth.dev/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms/) is an article which dives deeper into Angular Forms.